# dynamically creating question/field numbers in react js

Tags: html, reactjs, forms

We have a need to dynamically generate question/field numbers on react js for, for example -

if we have a form with 100 fields then all fields should have a number against them like -

1. question/field 1
2. question/field 2
   3 question/field 3
   ...
   ...
3. question/field 99
   100 question field 100

now if as per the visibilities and conditions on the fields, if few fields are not visible then the field numbering should shift up and all field numbers should still be sequential, for example if fields 34 and 45 are not visible for some condition then fields numbers would go from 1 to 98 like this -

1. question/field 1
2. question/field 2
3. question/field 3
   ...
   ...
4. question/field 33
5. question/field 35
   ...
6. question/field 47
7. question/field 48
   ...
8. question/field 99
9. question field 100

visibility is only on the field or question, the numbers would shift up and the number sequential would continue as shown above.

Please advise any optimal solution/design to achieve this.

thanks

fields with dynamically generated numbers in react js

Answer (score 0):

You can use two state variables

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function App() {

    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
    const [visibleQuestions, setVisibleQuestions] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let data = [];
        (new Array(100).fill(0)).forEach((el, i) => {
            data.push({
                id: i + 1,
                label: "question/field ",
                visibility: true
            })
        });
        setQuestions(data);
        setVisibleQuestions(data);
    }, [])


    const toggleDeleteButton = (index) => {
        questions[index]['visibility'] = false;
        setQuestions([...questions]);
        let visibleQs = questions.filter((question) => { return question.visibility });
        setVisibleQuestions([...visibleQs]);
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {
                visibleQuestions.map((ele, i) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={ele.label + ele.id + i}>
                            <div onClick={(e) => toggleDeleteButton(ele.id - 1)} >
                                {i + 1}. {ele.label} {ele.id}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default App
```